# Writing a Python dataframe to SQL Server but can't assign the primary key

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to write a dataframe to SQL Server and have one of the columns be not null and assigned the primary key for the table. I'm using df.tosql() and it's successfully creating and overwriting the table in SQL Server, but the method I'm using to then alter the table to make the column not null and a PK doesn't do anything.

Here's an example of my code snippet:

```py
engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))

df.to_sql('table_name', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

with engine.connect() as con:

        con.execute(text('ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column INTEGER NOT NULL;'))

        con.execute(text('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (`column`);'))
```

Again, writes the table fine to SQL Server but then altering that table is where I'm not seeing any results.

Comment: check so you actually commit the transaction

Comment: Did you use `con.commit()` right after `con.execute(...)`? 

Alternatively, you can add the line `with con.begin():` after `with engine.connect() as con:`. This way, `con` will be commited after the last statement within `with con.begin():`. Let us know if one of these methods work!

Comment: @TiMauzi i feel dumb now :') con.commit() worked with removing the `` around column, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is important to always commit your changes. Using SQLAlchemy, this works using the `con.commit()` statement after `con.execute(...)`.

```py
engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))

df.to_sql('table_name', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

with engine.connect() as con:

        con.execute(text('ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column INTEGER NOT NULL;'))

        con.execute(text('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (column);'))

        con.commit()
```

There are also other possible approaches which assure you that all changes are committed properly; e.g., using `with engine.begin():` before your `con.execute(...)` calls. For more information, see [the documentation.](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_transaction.html#session-level-vs-engine-level-transaction-control)